# Dynamic id to checkbox in Knockout foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, telerik, knockout-mapping-plugin

i am working on telerik application. in which i am using knockout.js to bind data in table.Code for foreach :

```
<tbody id="tbodySpeakerEvaluation" data-bind="foreach: SpeakerEvaluation">
```

Code to give dynamic value to checkbox is as follows :

```
<input data-enhanced="true" data-defaults="true" name="Contentaccuracy" data-bind="attr: {value: Id + '_1'}" type="checkbox">
```

i want my checkbox value should be Id_1 but this is not working. when i click on submit and getting checked checkbox its not giving me proper value for selected checkbox

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `Id` in quotes if it's just a string value you're trying to add:

```
<input data-enhanced="true" 
       data-defaults="true" 
       name="Contentaccuracy" 
       data-bind="attr: {value: 'Id' + '_1'}" type="checkbox">
```

Although you could just do: `{value: 'Id_1'}` if this is just a test.

Alternately, you could pass a property of `SpeakerEvaluation`, not sure if that's what you're trying to do? For instance if you had a `speakerId`property on `SpeakerEvaluation` you could do something like:

```
<input data-enhanced="true" 
       data-defaults="true" 
       name="Contentaccuracy" 
       data-bind="attr: {value: 'chk' + speakerId}" type="checkbox">
```

Or if `Id` is your property:

```
<input data-enhanced="true" 
       data-defaults="true" 
       name="Contentaccuracy" 
       data-bind="attr: {value: 'chk' + Id}" type="checkbox">
```

This way the value of each checkbox is related back to the `foreach` and will contain unique values if the Ids are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Make simple function randomNumber OR add function in your ViewModel OR use computed observable.

Let see using randomNumber function

```
function randomNumber(id) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random()).toString() + id;
}
```

This function call in attr bind like

```
<input data-enhanced="true" 
       data-defaults="true" 
       name="Contentaccuracy" 
       data-bind="attr: {value: randomNumber(Id)}" type="checkbox">
```